# Jquery not storing variable correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a piece of code that should capture the value (email address) of a form field upon form submit using an event listener, and then store that value in local storage. It's not working as expected and the form field value is never stored.

I'd appreciate some help troubleshooting.

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        if(jQuery( '.gravity-forms-form' ).length){
            document.querySelector('.gravity-forms-form').addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var submittedEmail = document.querySelector('.gravity-forms-form .ace_we input').value;
                console.log('submittedEmail'+submittedEmail);
                localStorage.setItem("visitorEmail", submittedEmail);
                _track();
                this.submit();  
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here's the HTML of a sample form (via Gravity Forms in WordPress):

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='gform_ajax_frame_13' id='gform_13' class='gravity-forms-form' action='/testing/?testnitro=1#gf_13' >
     <div class='gf_invisible ginput_recaptchav3' data-sitekey='6LdFM28bAAAAADA39VP-K0LcPDLFcfV934_Wfu1w' data-tabindex='1'>
          <input id="input_21cd1ec54a4692c23e99e5107eb16d86" class="gfield_recaptcha_response" type="hidden" name="input_21cd1ec54a4692c23e99e5107eb16d86" value=""/>
     </div>
     <div class='gform_body gform-body'>
          <div id='gform_fields_13' class='gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below'>
               <div id="field_13_1" class="gfield ace_we field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible" >
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_13_1' >Email</label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_email'>
                         <input name='input_1' id='input_13_1' type='text' value='' class='large' tabindex='2'    aria-invalid="false"  />
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class='gform_footer top_label'>
          <input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_13' class='gform_button button' value='Submit' tabindex='3' onclick='if(window["gf_submitting_13"]){return false;}  window["gf_submitting_13"]=true;  ' onkeypress='if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window["gf_submitting_13"]){return false;} window["gf_submitting_13"]=true;  jQuery("#gform_13").trigger("submit",[true]); }' />
          <input type='hidden' name='gform_ajax' value='form_id=13&amp;title=&amp;description=&amp;tabindex=1' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='is_submit_13' value='1' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_submit' value='13' />
            
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_unique_id' value='' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='state_13' value='WyJbXSIsImE5ZDQ0MjI1NjI4ZGJjYTBjN2VkNDlkYjBmNDUzOTU3Il0=' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_target_page_number_13' id='gform_target_page_number_13' value='0' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_source_page_number_13' id='gform_source_page_number_13' value='1' />
          <input type='hidden' name='gform_field_values' value='' />
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The code in your question works fine, aside from the invokation of `_track()` which isn't defined in the example, but I'm assuming exists somewhere in your codebase. You can see it working in this demo. Submit the form, then click the 'Check localstorage' button to see the value that was set: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4q3s8mx0/.

Comment: Also note that your code, while valid, uses a very odd mix of jQuery and native JS DOM access methods. Stick to one or the other. If you've included jQuery in the page you may as well make use of it, so the code would end up looking like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tmaf7j6q/

Comment: Thanks for checking and `_track()` is defined elsewhere in the script. I wonder why it's not working on the live site. I'll play around with the updated version you provided. Many thanks.